# Autocompletion ruby on rails editor for windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ide, autocomplete, editor

I am looking for an editor/IDE on windows doing autocompletion like eclipse (you start to type and there is a list of possible functions/variables). I tried Netbeans but it does not support network drives, I tried ruby mine, and aptana, but the tab gizmo requires you already know ruby on rails very well to be used.

Is there a Rails editor for windows with autocompletion?

Answer (score 2):

I think JetBrains makes the best IDEs on the market, hands down.  Take a look at their [Ruby Mine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/).  It's not free, but some things are worth paying for.

Comment: It does not recognise Rails. All the .all and .find function are declared as unknown...

Comment: Where did you see Rails autocompletion in RubyMine? You are giving your opinion without answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this thread:
[Ruby on Rails Editor for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172168/ruby-on-rails-editor-for-windows)

Answer (score 0):

[Aptana RadRails](http://www.aptana.com/products/radrails) is an extension for eclipse with ruby on rails support and is open source.

[RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) is also another good editor but it is not free.  RubyMine is surely a useful IDE but you might try the open source IDEs first.